# CSS not changing style of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the background color of a button in css. The CSS link is working fine, the button changes color when I try to apply bootstrap or use DOM to change the color, but not when I use CSS.

Here's the code:

```js
// let sexybutton= document.querySelector('.sexy');

// sexybutton.style.backgroundColor="red";

// console.log(sexybutton.style);

//Currently commented it out because I do not want to do it this way. Put this here to inform that the button style changes using this method.
```

```css
.body{
    background-color:#CCD6A6
};

.sexy{
    background-color: red
};
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fdee82af88.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="body" >
    <button class="sexy" type="submit">Click this</button>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: check browser console for errors or warnings (specifically regarding css)

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS syntax is wrong. The semi-colon `;` must be placed after each CSS property, not after each CSS rule.

```css
.body{
    background-color:#CCD6A6;
}

.sexy{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="body" >
    <button class="sexy" type="submit">Click this</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't a C/C++ or anything else that requires semicolon. You can't type a semi-colon to end of the style.

You wrote;

```css
.body{
    background-color:#CCD6A6
};

.sexy{
    background-color: red
};
```

but this is correct one;

```css
.body{
    background-color:#CCD6A6;
}

.sexy{
    background-color: red;
}
```

You must to write semicolon to end of the line. As you can see, line ending with `: red;`. Not like `};`

Answer (score 0):

it's unreadable, your semi-colon placement is not correct

```
.body{
background-color:#CCD6A6
};

.sexy{
background-color: red
};
```

correct

```
.body{
background-color:#CCD6A6;
}

.sexy{
background-color: red;
}
```